# How to apply background-color: css only in a webkit browser

Tags: css, background, webkit

Pretty simple, I have this tag

```
background: #4d4d4d;
```

and I need it only to work in WebKit browsers. Anyone know how to do this? Feel free to use any combination of PHP/JavaScript/jQuery/CSS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    if ($.browser.webkit) {
        $("body").css("background", "#4d4d4d");
    }
});
```

It'll work with current versions of jQuery, but it should be noted that jQuery.browser may be moved to a plugin in a future release of jQuery.

Answer (score 6):

```
[if Webkit]body
{
    background: #4d4d4d;
}
```

Source: http://www.conditional-css.com/

Or as many pointed out jQuery.

Or with

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) { 
    body
    {
        background: #4d4d4d
    }
}
```

Comment: Neither of these appear to be working in Chrome, so I guess jQuery will be the path of choice
EDIT: actually I don't know if these work or not, but my css minifier seems to completely remove these CSS methods

Comment: Great, at least I don't need JS for this.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery includes a method just for this.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.browser/

```
$.browser.webkit; //returns true
```